# 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable on linux with nodejs undefined by cordova

Tags: android, linux, node.js, cordova

Cordova installed correctly, Android SDK too.

```
# echo $ANDROID_HOME
/home/user/android-sdk-linux
```

But

```
# cordova build android --verbose
Error: CordovaError: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting setting it manually.
Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'. Try update your 'PATH' to include path to valid SDK directory.
at /home/user/myApp/platforms/android/cordova/lib/check_reqs.js:225:8
at _fulfilled (/home/user/myApp/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:834:54)
at self.promiseDispatch.done (/home/user/myApp/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:863:30)
at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/home/user/myApp/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:796:13)
at /home/user/myApp/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:857:14
at runSingle (/home/user/myApp/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:137:13)
at flush (/home/user/myApp/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:125:13)
at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:503:11)
at startup (node.js:129:16)
```

Ok... check variable by nodejs:

```
# node
> process.env['ANDROID_HOME']
'~/android-sdk-linux'
```

Everything seems good...
Ok... edit file "home/user/myApp/platforms/android/cordova/lib/check_reqs.js" (from error above) by adding next row:

```
if (!process.env['ANDROID_HOME']) {
  console.log(process.env['ANDROID_HOME']);
  throw new CordovaError('Failed to find \'ANDROID_HOME\' environment variable. Try setting setting it manually.\n' +
            'Failed to find \'android\' command in your \'PATH\'. Try update your \'PATH\' to include path to valid SDK directory.');
}
```

The result is:

```
# cordova build android --verbose
Executing "before_build"  hook for all plugins.
...
Executing "after_prepare"  hook for all plugins.
Executing "before_compile"  hook for all plugins.
**undefined**
Error: CordovaError: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting setting it manually.
```

How solve this problem with nodejs and cordova?

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**

for windows

Right click on My computer -> properties -> Advanced system setting -> Environment Variables

**Now Edit Path on system variables to ;/yourSdkHome/tools;/youSdkHome/platform-tools.**

**Option 2**

In Windows machine, Open Command prompt and enter each of this commands one by one

```
set ANDROID_HOME=C:\android-sdk-windows
set PATH=%PATH%;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools
```

In MAC Machine, open Terminal and enter these one by one

```
export ANDROID_HOME=//android-sdk-macosx export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

Note - C:\android-sdk-windows should be replaced by the path of Android SDK in your machine.

should be replaced by the path of Android SDK in your machine.

Example

in MAC machine, if install location is ~/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64/sdk

first line should be

```
export ANDROID_HOME=~/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64/sdk
```

Comment: Thats all done, problem in nodejs!
ANDROID_HOME variable defined in system, but not readable with js-files.